# ex navigation cannot press back on android after immediatelyResetStack

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, ex-navigation

I have this **login screen**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  _navigateToHome(){
    this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetStack([Router.getRoute('home')], 0);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {this._navigateToHome();}}
        activeOpacity={0.7}>
          <Text>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

When I press back on my Android, it works fine. Application exit with no stack history.

Then on my home screen, I have a drawer navigator with **logout menu**

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  render(){
    <DrawerNavigation
      drawerPosition="left"
      drawerWidth={300}
      initialItem="home"
    >
      <DrawerNavigationItem
        id={item.route}
        selectedStyle={styles.selectedItemStyle}
        renderTitle={isSelected => renderTitle('Home', isSelected)}
        >
          <View>Home Page</View>
      </DrawerNavigationItem>
      <DrawerNavigationItem
        id={item.route}
        selectedStyle={styles.selectedItemStyle}
        renderTitle={isSelected => renderTitle('Logout', isSelected)}
        onPress={()=> {
          this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetStack([Router.getRoute('login')], 0);
        }}
      />           
    </DrawerNavigation>
  }
}
```

When I press logout from the navigation drawer, it goes back to **login screen**, but when I press back from my **login screen**, the application didn't exit and I got this warning:

`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'currentNavigatorState.index')`

I have tried another workaround too, I use `replace` instead of `immediatelyResetStack` so it goes like this

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigator.replace('login')}
```

But I still got the exact same warning message, I tried putting `BackHandler` too on my **login screen**

```
componentWillMount() {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function () {
    BackHandler.exitApp();
  });
}
```

The application will exit, but when I go back to my application through the android menu button, the message still exists. How do I fix this?